# German written dialogue feedback?

Tags: grammaticality

Could you please tell me whether the following German dialogue is grammatically and idiomatically correct, and understandable to a native speaker?

For some context, it is a conversation between two military officers seated at a pub and sipping subpar schnapps while discussing the sad state of the war in which they’re engaged.

Peter is trying to convey to the point that, in spite of the suboptimal situation and any objections they might have to it, it is their duty as officers to make the most of it with a minimum of complaint.  I am hoping that comes across.

Thanks!

——

Noah: ‘Was ist das denn für’n Befehl?  Schrecklich, schrecklich.’

Peter: ‘Ja, und was ist das hier für’n Schnaps?  Genauso schrecklich.  Das wird wohl nichts mehr für uns, weder mit dem Schnaps noch mit dem Krieg.  Aber Dienst ist Dienst genau wie Schnaps ist Schnaps, so sagt man.’

Comment: Could you make your question specific please? As it stands, is not suitable for a Q&A-site. "Feedback" can be anything.

Comment: Sure thing.  My question is specifically: Is the German dialogue grammatically and idiomatically correct, and understandable in context to a (native) German speaker?  Sorry for any misunderstanding!

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Please rewrite and narrow down your question to focus on your problem as you started in your comment.

Comment: For story feedback exists worldbuilding.SE. Here you should skip any non-explanatory part and any non-english part. Also describe your intentions and where you struggle and why - like "found rule x and y, they just seem contrary - which one fits?"

Comment: Edited accordingly.  Thanks, and apologies if this is an inappropriate forum for this type of question.  Hopefully with the changes it is more in line with expectations.

Comment: PS: one change I would do is: `Aber Dienst ist Dienst, genauso wie Schnaps Schnaps ist[, wie man so sagt].`. And "`nichts mehr mit uns`". One problem to decide wether it is idiomatic or depends vastly on the social milieu - an indicator is the profession, just not causal linking. And then we still avoided speaking of dialects... E.g. usage of als and wie differs from Bavaria to Berlin.